# Scala Eclipse Error

Tags: eclipse, scala, netbeans

after the unsuccessful attempt to use Scala with NetBeans (Code Completion still doesn't work). I made up my mind and decided to try Eclipse. Due to the quarrels with NetBeans the path variable was already edited and I didn't expect any problems. Well, I was wrong.

1. I downloaded Eclipse Classic.
2. I read the instructions, how to setup the Scala IDE.
3. Following a youtube video, I installed all plugins available from this link http://www.scala-ide.org/
4. I created a new Scala project and added an object to it.

First a window appeared showing this information

> An error has occurred. See error log
>   for more details.
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

I looked in the error log, but I don't know what to do. There are four different errors.

1. Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
2. Widget disposed too early!
3. Unhandled event loop exception
4. Failure in presentation compiler

Pretty impressing isn't it ? What shall I do ?

Comment: "I downloaded NetBeans Classic" You mean Eclipse Classic, right?

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Galileo or Helios? Did you install the Scala IDE from corresponding (ie. Galileo or Helios) specific update site?

Comment: Also, was it a stable or development release of the plugin?

Comment: I corrected my mistake. Of course I meant Eclipse Classic. I downloaded version 3.6.1. I've don't think this is Helios already but I'm not sure. Moreover I downloaded the plugin from http://www.scala-ide.org/. It was a stable build.

Comment: Actually it is Helios. I just checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to an earlier comment you say,

> I downloaded version 3.6.1. I've don't
>   think this is Helios already but I'm
>   not sure. Moreover I downloaded the
>   plugin from scala-ide.org. It was a
>   stable build.stable build.

Eclipse 3.6.1 is Eclipse Helios. That means that you need to install the Helios-specific version of the Scala tooling from it's update site [here](http://download.scala-ide.org/) ... this is pretty clearly flagged up on [scala-ide.org](http://www.scala-ide.org/): see the text "Experimental support for Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) is available" and the corresponding link. Alternatively you can revert to Eclipse 3.5.x (Galileo).

Also, please note that the best place to get support for the Scala IDE for Eclipse is the [scala-ide-user mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user) ... I keep an eye on stackoverflow for questions like this, but in general you'll get a much faster and more reliable response if you post your questions to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke Eclipse with `eclipse -clean` then go to Window, Preferences, JDT Weaving and click Enable then restart your Eclipse and try creating a new Scala project again.

Let us know how was it.

Comment: eclipse -clean failed somehow. Moreover JDT Weaving was already set. What is JDT Weaving anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

I invoked Eclipse with

> eclipse -clean

but JDT Weaving was already enabled. I never changed its value so this is slightly confusing. Nevertheless I created a new Scala project and the same error ocurred. Additionally in the error log I found the message

> The -clean (osgi.clean) option was not
>   successful. Unable to clean the
>   storage area:
>   D:\Programme\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi

What went wrong ? The command line didn't spit out any error message.

Comment: Yeah, @Miles, this a major issue with Eclipse installed by Linux distributions.

Comment: Eclipse is installed in a writable location and I'm using windows.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of being flamed....

Have you tried IntelliJ, it's free if you use the community edition and currently seems to have the strongest/most stable support for Scala of the 3 major (Java) IDEs.